# WinPcap/Wireshark install: where is packet.dll?

Tags: windows-8.1, wireshark

I have Wireshark installed, and I'm getting this error:

> The NPF driver isn't running.  You may have trouble capturing or listing interfaces.

I realize this is something to do with WinPcap. It's not in control panel, as the FAQ states it should be. I've tried installing it, and it says that there is a previous version installed. This leaves me to believe this is the problem:

> To be absolutely sure that WinPcap has been installed, please look at your system folder: you should find files called packet.* and wpcap.dll. Please check the file dates: these should be compatible with the WinPcap release dates. We've had reports of trojans or other malware that silently install the WinPcap driver, NPF.sys. If you've been infected by them, you'll probably see the driver file in Windows\System32\Drivers, but no entries in the "Add or Remove Programs" applet and no dlls.

I've searched my hard drive, but the only path is this:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\packet.dll
```

Is this the file they are talking about? Should I delete this file? I'm not quite sure, so I thought I'd verify that this file is the right one.

Comment: With wireshark-on win7 32bit I have C:\>dir packet.dll /s/b<ENTER>
C:\Windows\System32\Packet.dll    And I have winpcap in ctrl panel.. 'programs and features'  Can't wireshark remove the existing winpcap and install fresh?  Try installing winpcap separately.  On w7 64bit C:\Windows\System32\Packet.dll
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Packet.dll

Comment: @barlop Did you not read my post? *It's not in control panel* **AND** *I've tried installing it*.

Comment: I am confirming for you that winpcap should be.  And you tried installing what? Wireshark? Winpcap? Both?

Comment: @barlop Wireshark was already installed, I'm installing Winpcap

Comment: Your question is completely unclear and you are still unclear. Wireshark gives an error about the NPF driver OK.  And then what.. You  seem to be searching trying to find out if you have winpcap and you check a FAQ(and quote it but you don't even say you got that from a FAQ so some might think it was an error message like the last thing you quoted). You haven't said anything at all about what happens when you try to install winpcap. Does it try to uninstall a previous version. Does it complete and not give any error.

Comment: Furthermore you don't have to be frightened about "deleting" a file. Rename the file. And if things break then rename it back.

Comment: @barlop It gives me an error. I have researched that, and it's commonly associated with no Winpcap. I noticed it wasn't in control panel. I tried installing it, but it gives me an error that it's already installed. This makes me think that it's that .dll file. And yes, I've said what it says when I install it *...something to do with WinPcap. It's not in control panel, as the FAQ states it should be. I've tried installing it, and it says that there is a previous version installed.*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14768/discussion-between-barlop-and-annonomus-penguin).